# iOS 4.3 PDF file rendering issue

Tags: objective-c, ios, pdf, ios4

I use the following code to draw and rotate a PDF file. It works perfectly fine with [iOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IOS_%28Apple%29) 5.x, but under iOS 4.3 just a white page shows up with an error in the debugger:

> invalid `Contents': not an array of streams.

The error takes place right after "CGContextDrawPDFPage(context, pdfPage);"

Why does it work with iOS 5.x but does not 4.3.x? I tried different PDF files, but still I got the same result.

How do I overcome this issue?

pdfpage is defined as:

```
- (void)setPage:(CGPDFPageRef)newPage
{
    CGPDFPageRelease(self->pdfPage);
    self->pdfPage = CGPDFPageRetain(newPage);
}
```

the method where it happens:

```
 -(void)drawLayer:(CALayer*)layer inContext:(CGContextRef)context
{
    // First fill the background with white.
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0);
    CGContextFillRect(context,self.bounds);
    CGContextSaveGState(context);
    int rotate = CGPDFPageGetRotationAngle(pdfPage);

    switch (rotate) {
        case 0:
            CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0.0, self.bounds.size.height);
            CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1, -1);
            break;
        case 90:
            CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);
            CGContextRotateCTM(context, -M_PI / 2);
            break;
        case 180:
        case -180:
            CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1, -1);
            CGContextTranslateCTM(context, self.bounds.size.width, 0);
            CGContextRotateCTM(context, M_PI);
            break;
        case 270:
        case -90:
            CGContextTranslateCTM(context, self.bounds.size.height, self.bounds.size.width);
            CGContextRotateCTM(context, M_PI / 2);
            CGContextScaleCTM(context, -1, 1);
            break;
    }

    CGContextSetInterpolationQuality(context, kCGInterpolationHigh);
    CGContextSetRenderingIntent(context, kCGRenderingIntentDefault);
    CGContextScaleCTM(context, myScale,myScale);
    CGContextDrawPDFPage(context, pdfPage); // the error shows up right after executing this line
    CGContextRestoreGState(context);
}
```

Comment: what is 'pdfPage'? check if its initialized properly.

Comment: please note that down/up voting doesnt help me to solve the problem!

Comment: @MitulNakum its initialized properly it works with ios 5.x but not ios 4.3.x i have update the code. thanks for trying to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to PDF specification, the /Contents entry in the page dictionary can be either a stream object or an array of stream objects. Based on the error message, it seems the iOS 4.3 does not properly implement the PDF specification, it always expects an array of streams for the /Contents entry and your files use a single stream object. iOS 5 probably fixed this problem.

Comment: i went back to apple pdf render example, now it works with ios 4.3 too. but i didn't get it what problem was. anyway if someone has the problem, just take alook at apple's example

Comment: After hours trying to find what is the difference, between the 2 samples (ZoomingPDFViewer), I finally found it. Prior to iOS 5, you need to keep a reference to the PDFDocument and release it in the dealloc. After iOS 5, you can release just after passing the CGPDFPageRef to the TiledView. Why ? Don't know.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do `CGPDFDocumentRetain(yourCGPDFDocumentRef)` at first.